# Excel line chart plot multiple y values (series) on same x value

Tags: excel, scatter-plot, linechart

I am trying to plot multiple y values for the same series on the same x value in a line chart across a period of time. As a background, I would like to create a line chart (or scatter plot) of rankings for a particular professor over a period of time. However, the problem lies in that professors teach multiple sections in a given quarter. As a result, I’m unable to utilize a series to encapsulate more than one section for a given period, which results in each section having its own series (as opposed to each professor having their own series that captures all sections they teach). I would like for each professor to show up as one series (i.e., color) across time in the chart. Any help would be great!

[image: excel data]
[image: excel chart]

[final chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/69vFN.jpg)

Comment: Generate a new table with one row for each professor?

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad, I may be misunderstanding, but creating one row for each professor would eliminate the ability to chart multiple sections that a professor teaches in a given quarter, which I would still like to have the ability to see in the chart

Comment: "...as opposed to each professor having their own series..." kind of implies you want one row (i.e. series) for each professor... Maybe edit your question to clarify it?

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad I follow. I updated to include the fact that I would like each professor and their associated sections to be included in the chart under the same series.

I also included a new picture ("final chart") of what I ideally would like for the final result to look like. In arriving at this last picture, I had to manually update the color of each marker to match for each professor, which took a bit of time to do (and what I'd ideally like to solve for here).